# Django reverse relationship name gives invalid keyword argument error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
  class Catalogue(Base):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

        params = models.ForeignKey("Params", related_name="params_item", null=True, blank=True)

    class Params(Base):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

But when I do this:

```
Params.objects.create(params_item=object_cat, name="Test")
```

I get the error:

**params_item' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

Why can I not use the reverse relation name to set this?

Comment: It would be better to choose a name like "catalogues" for the related_name instead of "params_item". When you use the related name, it is to get the related catalogues for a given params, so `catalogues = params.catalogues.all()` is better than `catalogues = params.params_item.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse relation can be used to query related items, but you can't use it to set the object as you are trying.

You need to create the params, then update the related object.

```
params = Params.objects.create(name="Test")
object_cat.params = params
object_cat.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it this way, that's not how you use a reverse relation. You have to do it this way instead

```
...
param = Params(name='Some Param')
param.save()

catalog = Catalog(name='Some Catalog')
catalog.params = param
catalog.save()
```

Then you'd use the reverse relation to query the list of catalogs related to it like so

```
catalogs = param.params_item.all()
```